# Powershell move-item file in use

Tags: powershell, csv, locked-files, select-string

Trying to match a string in a bunch of CSV files and then move those with the string to another folder. The script logic seems to work but I keep getting errors that the file is use.  I imagine it is powershell that has the file locked.  How can I work around this?

```
$DestDir = "C:\temp\NEWCSV"
$SrcDir = "C:\temp\CSV"
$SearchString = "teststring"
gci $SrcDir -filter *.csv | select-string $SearchString | select path | move-item -dest $DestDir -whatif
```

Comment: What is the exact error you're getting? Do you have an anti-virus program that might be interfering? What OS and PowerShell version are you on? Does this happen with other files/folders, or just this `c:\temp` directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why your script doesn't work, unless the Select-String is keeping the file open as an object being passed down the pipe. If you rephrase it like this it'll work:

```
$DestDir = "C:\temp\NEWCSV"
$SrcDir = "C:\temp\CSV"
$SearchString = "TITLE"
gci $SrcDir -filter *.csv | ?{select-string $SearchString $_ -quiet}|move-item -Destination $DestDir
```

Comment: Thanks "TheMadTechnician"!  Your rephrase made it work perfectly.  Not sure I understand the exact reason but I sure appreciate the eyes on it!